# While extracting a zip file after downloading, exception occurs saying that the file is being used by another process

Tags: c#, zip

I am downloading a zip file and then  trying to extract it using the 
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory method. I get an exception stating that the zip file is being used by another process.

I tried to use thread.sleep to wait for the download process to dispose of the file but the exception still occurs

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code you have. This will allow people to look at it and see if there is a relevant solution that they can propose.

Comment: If you used a Stream to store the file on disc, you probably haven't closed/disposed of the Stream. You should show what you mean with *I used thread.sleep to wait for the download process (...)*.